# How to make nodejs readline prompt and history work

Tags: node.js

I confused with usage of readline in NodeJs.  I wrote:

```
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    prompt: '> ',
});
rl.on('line', line => {
    console.log(line);
});
```

With above, I cannot get expected prompt '>' and I cannot get the Up key work for bringing in the history.  If I add 'terminal: true' when create the readline, I then get the Up key working but I cannot see what I typed in the console.  In both cases, I cannot get the prompt.

What I expected is: It always print a prompt '> ' and waiting for my input. Every key I entered it should display on the console. Once I entered the Enter key, my callback get invocation and it gives me a newline and another prompt.

How should I archive this?  Thanks in advance!

-woody

Comment: You have to specify `output: process.stdout` as well. That should resolve both problems.

Comment: It looks like `rl.on` is an event handler and not a method which asks the user to input data.

Comment: Many thanks!  Adding 'output: process.stdout' works greatly!